# How to get all possible paths in 0/1 matrix better way?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

[image]

This picturel can be generated like this

```
pos={{1,4},{1,8},{1,9},{2,2},{2,3},{2,4},{2,5},{2,6},{2,8},{2,9},{3,2},{3,6},{4,1},{4,2},{4,3},{4,4},{4,5},{4,6},{4,7},{4,8},{5,2},{5,7},{6,2},{6,5},{6,6},{6,7},{7,2},{7,5},{7,8},{8,2},{8,4},{8,5},{8,6},{8,7},{8,8},{8,9},{9,2}};
m=SparseArray[pos->0,{9,9},1];
ArrayPlot[m,Mesh->All]
```

Although I got the result, but in an hard coded way, lack of flexibility

```
g = Graph[Range[81], 
  UndirectedEdge @@@ {36 -> 35, 17 -> 26, 26 -> 35, 35 -> 44, 
    44 -> 53, 17 -> 16, 16 -> 15, 15 -> 14, 14 -> 13, 13 -> 12, 
    12 -> 11, 11 -> 10, 6 -> 15, 15 -> 24, 24 -> 33, 33 -> 42, 
    42 -> 51, 51 -> 60, 60 -> 59, 59 -> 58, 58 -> 49, 49 -> 40, 
    40 -> 39, 39 -> 38, 29 -> 38, 38 -> 47, 47 -> 56, 56 -> 65, 
    65 -> 74, 66 -> 65, 71 -> 72, 72 -> 81, 81 -> 80, 80 -> 71, 
    53 -> 52, 51 -> 52, 60 -> 69}, { 
   VertexCoordinates -> Tuples[Range[9], 2]}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
FindPath[%, 36, 74, Infinity, All]
HighlightGraph[g, PathGraph[#]] & /@ %
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`NearestNeighborGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NearestNeighborGraph.html) with `pos` directly:

```
nng = NearestNeighborGraph[pos, VertexCoordinates -> RotationTransform[-Pi/2][pos], 
  VertexLabels->"Name"]
```

[image]

```
Row[HighlightGraph[nng, Subgraph[nng, #], ImageSize -> 300] & /@ 
  FindPath[nng, {1, 4}, {8, 9}, ∞, All], Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

If a binary matrix `m` is given as input, you can use `pos = SparseArray[m]["NonzeroPositions"]` before the first line of code above.

To show  `ArrayPlot` and the graph together we need to translate the vertex coordinates to align with cells in `ArrayPlot`:

```
Show[ArrayPlot[SparseArray[pos -> 1], ColorRules -> {1->Opacity[.5, Yellow]}, Mesh -> All],
  NearestNeighborGraph[pos, 
  VertexCoordinates -> TranslationTransform[{-.5, 9.50}]@RotationTransform[-Pi/2][pos], 
  VertexLabels -> "Name"]]
```

[image]

Use `IndexGraph @ NearestNeighborGraph[...]` above to replace each vertex with its index:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this helps. It requires Szabolcs' package [`` "IGraphM`" ``](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM). It is very easy to install and it provides many useful tools for working with graphs.

```
Needs["IGraphM`"]

A = Reverse@(1 - m);
R = ArrayMesh[Normal@A];
{i, j} = Transpose@UpperTriangularize[IGMeshCellAdjacencyMatrix[R, 2, 2], 1][ "NonzeroPositions"];

vertices = A["NonzeroPositions"][[All, {2, 1}]];
edges = Transpose[{vertices[[i]], vertices[[j]]}];


G = Graph[vertices, UndirectedEdge @@@ edges,
 VertexCoordinates -> vertices,
 VertexLabels -> "Name"
 ]
```

[image]

An now, we can request all paths:

```
paths = FindPath[G, {4, 9}, {9, 2}, Infinity, All];
GraphicsRow[
 HighlightGraph[G, Subgraph[G, #]] & /@ paths, 
 ImageSize -> Full
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I'd do it like this with [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM):

```
mesh = ArrayMesh@Normal[1 - m]
```

[image]

```
g = IGMeshCellAdjacencyGraph[mesh, 2, VertexCoordinates -> Automatic, 
  VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]

There are two paths:

```
paths = FindPath[g, {2, 1}, {2, 36}, Infinity, All]

Length[paths]
(* 2 *)
```

If `PathGraph` didn't dislike certain vertex names that are lists, we could show them like this:

```
HighlightGraph[g, PathGraph[#]] & /@ paths
```

To work around this limitation, we define our own `pathGraph` function:

```
pathGraph[path_] := Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ Partition[path, 2, 1]]
```

[image]